# Modify a number following a certain structure in powershell

Tags: powershell

In powershell, i'm trying to replace the first number of each phone number with 0.
One way to find the phone number is to search for numbers with 10 digits followed by , thats what i did below.
The problem is that those phone numbers are repeated somewhere else in the file, without any structure. So how can i add a: Go search for the same numbers you modified in the file (the ten digits followed by ), and modify them the same way.

Thanks for your help

```
 $file_content = Get-Content "$original_file"
Set-Content -Path "$destination_file" -Value ($file_content -replace "\d(\d{9})(?=<Phone>)", "0`$1")
```

Comment: Could you add an example of `$original_file` and your desired outcome to your question?

Comment: `-replace` should be already updating all appearances of 10 digits, so my guess is that, you want to replace the first match with your regex and then update all appearances of that match.

Comment: Yes sir, because not all the numbers of 10 digits in the file are phone numbers.
Exactly, i want to replace the first match then replace all appearances of that match

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easier way of doing this, first get all the values that matches *"`10` digits followed by the word `(phone)`"* and store those matches in a *hash table* where the **keys** are the **10 digits** that need to be replaced and the **values** are **0 + the 9 remaining digits**.

Then we can use the [`Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) method to replace all appearances of the 10 digits matched before (the *hash table* keys).

```
$string = @'
1111111111
AAA BBB 1234567890 BD 1111111111(phone)
2222222222
ABC 2222222222 CDK 23456789012 CD 2222222222(phone)
'@

$map = @{}

[regex]::Matches($string, '(?i)(\d(\d{9}))\(phone\)').ForEach({
    $map[$_.Groups[1].Value] = '0' + $_.Groups[2].Value
})

[regex]::Replace($string, ($map.Keys -join '|'), {
    param([string]$matched)
    $map[$matched]
})
```

Your code should look like this assuming this is what you needed.

**Note the use of the `-Raw` switch is mandatory in this case.**

```
$map = @{}
$content = Get-Content $original_file -Raw

[regex]::Matches($content, '(?i)(\d(\d{9}))\(phone\)').ForEach({
    $map[$_.Groups[1].Value] = '0' + $_.Groups[2].Value
})

$replacedContent = [regex]::Replace($content, ($map.Keys -join '|'), {
    param([string]$matched)
    $map[$matched]
})

Set-Content -Path $destination_file -Value $replacedContent
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser,  I have an issue tho, I can see that it modified the first phone number, but not the 100 other phone numbers

Comment: @walbenme93 if you add an example of how your file looks to your question I could see what's going on as this should replace all appearances of the first match